# What is the expectation of a variable that has two cases (being either 0 or a constant) depending on a normal distributed variable

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, stochastic-processes

I need to determine the expectation of a variable: $\mathbb{E}(b(v))$

The value $b$ has two cases: it is either 0 when $v<0$ or a constant c when $v\geq 0$. The value $v$ has a normal distribution.

How can you determine the expectation of $b(v)$?

Comment: Apparently this is a homework question. Please add the self-study tag. And here is a hint: Write down the formula for the expectation value of b, which only has two summands.

Comment: Another hint: introduce the indicator functions $\mathbb I_{V<0}$ and  $\mathbb I_{V>0}$ in the expectation.

Comment: **Apply the formula for the expectation.**  It's simple, because $b(v)$ has only two values -- you need only multiply each value by its probability and add up the results.  It's *super* simple because one of those values is zero and therefore does not introduce anything into the answer!